# How to adjust speed of smoothScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I am currently using the `smoothScroll` function on a horizontally scrolling website. The current jQuery I have running is both for a previous/next section button and a regular navigation for all sections. The regular navigation is that with the .scroll-test class. This is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = 1;

    $('a.forward').click(function () {
        url = url + 1;
        $(this).attr({ href: '#section' + url });
        $(this).parent().attr({ class: 'section' + url });
    });

    $('a.backward').click(function () {
        url = url - 1;
        $(this).attr({ href: '#section' + url });
        $(this).parent().attr({ class: 'section' + url });
    });

    $('a.forward, a.backward').smoothScroll();
    $('a.scroll-test').smoothScroll();
});
```

What I want is to change the speed of the scroll animation. Right now it's going really fast when jumping over more than one page.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you set the speed by passing it a param (object) to the function like so

```
.smoothScroll({speed:2000})
```

The speed value is the animation time in milliseconds

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks alot